# condicion de carrera con cursores en mongodb

Tags: mongodb

la consulta es acerca de la utilizacion de cursores con mongodb. no me queda claro como el motor soluciona la condion de carrera cuando genera un cursor y otro cliente hace un update / insert.
Entiendo que esto no sucede con las dbs relacionales, pero no estoy seguro de como se menaja dicha condicion de “carrera" con un motor nosql.
Desde ya muchas gracias.